# What is the correct way to replace "csxdef/foreach" with pure expl3 code?

Tags: macros, expl3, latex3

I'm trying to remove the dependencies of the packages `pgffor` and `etoolbox` from a code I own which uses `expl3`, but I don't know which is the correct equivalent of `\csxdef` in `expl3`. At the moment I have the following code, which works, but I don't know if it's the right way to replace it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmdone}{ m m }
  {
   \_csxdef_pgfetoolbox:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \_csxdef_pgfetoolbox:nn #1 #2
  {
  \foreach \x [count=\n] in { #2 } { \csxdef{#1\n}{\x} }  % save in \#1<n>
  }

\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmdtwo}{ m m }
  {
    \_csxdef_expl:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  }

\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \_csxdef_expl:nn #1 #2 
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#2}
    \int_step_inline:nn { \clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist } 
      {
        \cs_set:cpx {l_#1##1:} {  \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist { ##1 }  }
      }   
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Test mycmdone
\mycmdone{A}{X,Y,Z,W}
\csuse{A1} \csuse{A2} \csuse{A3} \csuse{A4}
% repeat
\mycmdone{A}{X,Y,Z,W}
\csuse{A1} \csuse{A2} \csuse{A3} \csuse{A4}
\par

Test mycmdtwo
\mycmdtwo{B}{P,Q,R}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\use:c{l_B1:} ~ \use:c{l_B2:} ~ \use:c{l_B3:}
\ExplSyntaxOff
% repeat
Test mycmdtwo
\mycmdtwo{B}{P,Q,R}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\use:c{l_B1:} ~ \use:c{l_B2:} ~ \use:c{l_B3:}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

Commands take two arguments, where the second is separated by commas and is not used directly in the document, `\csuse` is passed as an argument to another code I have defined. I don't know if what I should use is `\cs_new:` or `\l_#1#2_tl` or if `expl3` has a function that already does this (I don't want to reinvent the wheel).

Greetings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is more of a comment that is too long for a comment....

Since it seems that you want to be able to redefine these commands I think that you need to use `\cs_set:cpx` (or `\cs_gset:cpx` or `\cs_set:cx` or `\cs_set:cx`), but you don't need two functions here and, instead, the following is sufficient:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmdtwo}{ m m }
  {
    \clist_set:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {#2}
    \int_step_inline:nn {\clist_count:N \l_tmpa_clist}
    {
      \cs_set:cpx {l_#1##1:} { \clist_item:Nn \l_tmpa_clist {##1} }
    }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\mycmd{m}{\use:c{l_#1:}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

Test mycmdtwo
\mycmdtwo{B}{P,Q,R}
\mycmd{B1} \mycmd{B2} \mycmd{B3}

% repeat
Test mycmdtwo
\mycmdtwo{B}{P,Q,R}
\mycmd{B1} \mycmd{B2} \mycmd{B3}

\end{document}
```

I have also given a "helper" command `\mycmd`.

You can also use `\cs_set:cx` or `\cs_gset:cx` but, as Joseph points out in the comments, `\cs_set:cpx` and `\cs_gset:cpx` are much faster.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation, in fact the saying using `pgffor|csxdef` I took it from (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/378258/7832) which is an answer from yourself.

Comment: The `p` versions are much faster ...

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 5):

I'd do a little different. The code as you put it iterates through the comma list `2+<num>` times, with `<num>` being the number of items in the list. The first iteration is in `\clist_set:Nn`, which loops through it trimming spaces. The second iteration is in `\clist_count:N`, which loops again to count the number of items. And as many iterations as there are items in the list with `\clist_item:Nn`, which doesn't just skip to the item you want, but scans each item until it finds the one you want. It's rather suboptimal. In fact, using `l3benchmark` to measure the performance, 10 thousand iterations of your code runs in 1.32 s, while the code below runs in 0.39 s, more than 3x speedup.

I suggest using `\clist_map_inline:nn` (or something similar), which will iterate only once through the list, and use an auxiliary counter to keep track of the item number.

I'd say that you should use a `<tl var>` here with `\tl_new:c` and `\tl_set:cx` rather than `\cs_set:cx` (which, by the way, is much slower than `\cs_set:cpx`). And, since the generated items aren't functions (in `expl3` terminology), but variables, this alternative seems better. Then the accessor function can just be changed to be `\tl_use:c`, which will check if the requested variable exists and issue an error if appropriate. Using `\use:c` here is not desired because if the requested variable does not exist it will expand to `\relax` and will not raise an error.

Finally, if you plan to reuse the created token lists, then instead of `\tl_new:c` (which raises an error if the variable exists), you can use `\tl_clear_new:c` which will clear the variable, or create it, depending if it existed or not.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_new:N \l_pablo_tmp_int
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmdtwo}{ m m }
  {
    \int_zero:N \l_pablo_tmp_int
    \clist_map_inline:nn {#2}
      {
        \int_incr:N \l_pablo_tmp_int
        \tl_clear_new:c { l_pablo_#1 \int_use:N \l_pablo_tmp_int _tl } % Redundant here, but good practice in general
        \tl_set:cx { l_pablo_#1 \int_use:N \l_pablo_tmp_int _tl } {##1}
      }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand\mycmd {m} { \tl_use:c { l_pablo_#1_tl } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
Test mycmdtwo
\mycmdtwo{B}{P,Q,R}
\mycmd{B1} \mycmd{B2} \mycmd{B3}

% repeat
Test mycmdtwo
\mycmdtwo{B}{P,Q,R}
\mycmd{B1} \mycmd{B2} \mycmd{B3}
\end{document}
```

**TeXhackers note:** `\tl_set:cx` does `\cs_set_nopar:cpx` (*i.e.,* `\expandafter\xdef\csname...\endcsname`, so the `\tl_new:c` is redundant. But it is in the best practices to declare the variable before using it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I had my doubts about the correct use of `cs_new` vs `\tl_new`, putting `\tl_new:c `is almost obligatory in my case, otherwise it doesn't happen when using `debug_on:n {...}` (which I think is good practice :). Query ... Is there a difference between `use:c` and `\tl_use:c`?

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL `\use:c{name}` is exactly `\csname name\endcsname`. If `\name` exists it will be used and if it is not TeX will implicitly `\let\name\relax` and use it with no error message. `\tl_use:c` uses `\tl_use:N`, which checks if the `tl var` exists before using it and prints and error message if it does not. So again, in the realm of best practices, `\tl_use:c` is a better option because it will not silently do something you don't want it to. (Sorry for the delay, I posted the answer right before going to bed and just woke up :-)

Comment: ...Okay, I understand, one last query (if you can add to your answer). If I need to rewrite `\mycmdtwo` (repeat) should I occupy `\use:c` or should I change `\tl_new:c` to `\tl_clear_new:c `?...Saludos

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL If you want to do `\mycmdtwo{B}{P,Q,R}` again to overwrite the token lists, then `\tl_clear_new:c` is the way to go. I'll add to the answer. Only in very specific situations `\use:c` will be the correct choice, mainly due to its implicit behaviour.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation and analysis.

Answer (score 4):

Token list variables are different from functions. Your code is meant to store token lists, rather than define actions.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\mycmd}{mm}
 {
  \seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l__pablo_mycmd_seq { #2 }
  \seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn \l__pablo_mycmd_seq
   {
    \tl_clear_new:c { l_pablo_#1##1_tl }
    \tl_set:cn { l_pablo_#1##1_tl } { ##2 }
   }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\pablouse}{m}
 {
  \tl_use:c { l_pablo_#1_tl }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Test mycmd
\mycmd{A}{X,Y,Z,W}

\pablouse{A1} \pablouse{A2} \pablouse{A3} \pablouse{A4}

\end{document}
```

A benchmark of my solution compared with Phelype Oleynik's yields

```
8.22e-5 seconds (252 ops)
1.08e-4 seconds (321 ops)
```

Top is my solution, bottom is Phelype's.

Comment: Thank you, I missed `\seq_indexed_map_inline:Nn` when reading the documentation.

Comment: Query, compared to the answer given by @Phelype Oleinik, which is more efficient?

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL I did the benchmark.

Comment: Thank you very much...again. Saludos