# Add Multiple Arguments To Command With Comma

Tags: macros

Is there any way to define a command like:

```
\newcommand{\mysum}[2]{\sum\limits_{#1}^{#2}}
```

where the two arguments are separated by a comma instead of brackets?

So for example, I'd like to have:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%yet to be defined command%

\begin{document}
The sum given by $a=\mysum{n=1, \infty}$
\end{document}
```

Return the same thing as:

```
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
The sum given by $a=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: E.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378252/renewcommand-with-comma-separated-arguments

Comment: Hello! excuse me, but what would be the advantage of using comma rather brakets?

Comment: @Dario just faster. Less characters and no need to hit shift key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

expl3's `\clist_item:nn` might be your friend:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt, letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \mysum #1 {\sum\limits\sb{\clist_item:nn{#1}{1}}\sp{\clist_item:nn{#1}{2}}} 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
The sum given by $a=\mysum{n=1, \infty}$

The sum given by $a=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'd not add `\limits` unconditionally and use a *-variant if you need it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\NewDocumentCommand{\mysum}{s >{\SplitArgument{1}{,}}m}{%
  \sum
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\limits}%
  \mysumaux#2%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\mysumaux}{mm}{_{#1}\IfValueT{#2}{^{#2}}}

\begin{document}

$\mysum{n=1,\infty}$ is good.

$\mysum*{n=1,\infty}$ is bad.
\[
\mysum{n=1,\infty}\qquad \mysum{n\ge0}
\]

\end{document}
```

You see that a single item in the argument is correctly treated as a subscript.

[image]